# Is destructor called at the end of main(); strange behavior

Tags: c++, destructor

```
// Foo.h

class Foo
{

public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
    void exec();
};


// Foo.cpp

Foo::~Foo()
{
    // Statements A
    exit(0);
}

//main.cpp

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.exec();

    // Statements B
    return 0;
}
```

So why both Statements A and B get executed? And is the destructor called when we reach return 0?

I have seen variants where `void exec();` is `int exec();` and the `main` function ends with
`return foo.exec();` does this calls the destructor?

Because I want to have an object that takes control of the code flow from the main function and end the program later.

Answer (score 2):

The destructor, and hence statement A, is executed as part of the processing of the `return 0` statement B. This is a simple guarantee in C++, that the destructor of a local object with automatic storage, is executed automatically when the execution leaves the object's scope.

Answer (score 2):

The destructor is called once the `main` function returns, i.e. after the `return` statement, just like local objects in any other function.

As for `return someObject.someFunction();`, the expression in the `return` statement must be fully evaluated before the `return` statement can actually return anything, because it needs the result of that expression. So if the function contains a long-running loop (like a GUI event loop) then it might take quite some time before the `return` statement actually returns.