# Destructor trouble

Tags: class, oop, destructor

I've recently read that if you use an object of a class as a reciving parameter of a function, a copy of an object has to be created automaticly. Therefore, if the destructor is included in the class, both original object and it's copy will be vanished automaticly. However, when I tried to make a small code with the same conception destructor only activated once. What can cause the problem? Thanks in advance!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
int val;
public:

MyClass(int i)
{
    val = i;
    cout << "Constructor is in progress" << endl;
}

void SetVal(int i)
{
    val = i;
}

int GetVal()
{
    return val;
}

~MyClass()
{
    cout << "Destructer is in progress" << endl;
}
};


void Display(MyClass obj)
{
cout << obj.GetVal();
}

int main()
{
MyClass a(10);

cout << "Before display()" << endl;
Display(a);
cout << "After display()" << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called after the return statement. The first message you are seeing is from the copied object. When you get to `system("pause")` your original object is still in scope, so the destructor is not called. It is called after the return statement is evaluated.

[Is destructor called at the end of main(); strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387000/is-destructor-called-at-the-end-of-main-strange-behavior)